# Function call returns - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head' - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a function for opening different files as pandas dataframes through the following code. However, calling the function and printing information of the dataframe generated throws `'Nonetype'` error. Where am I going wrong?

## Step1: Function for opening multiple files:

```
place='NewDelhi'

def filename(year):
   file='/Users/dishas/Desktop/US_aq_data/'+place+'/'+place+'_'+'PM2.5_'+str(year)+'_YTD.csv'
   df=pd.read_csv(file)
   print 'file name', file
   print 'head'
   print df.head()


df1=filename(2015)
print 'outside of function - details'
print df1.head()
quit()
```

Comment: Would you mind fixing your formatting and indentation? I don't want to assume the indentation levels and make a bad edit that misrepresents your question/code

Comment: You can fix your formatting by clicking the edit button underneath your question, the comment doesn't preserve formatting for blocks of code

Comment: Your function doesn't actually return anything. Are you supposed to return `df` or `df.head()` from the function?

Comment: Yes, adding return is helpful. But still I am unable to print dataframe details outside the function (eg. dataframe.head()). It says - 'function' object has no attribute 'head'.

Comment: @Disha Then are you returning the correct object?

Comment: Yes, now returning df in the function....Very useful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
\\\place='NewDelhi'

def filename(year):
   file='/Users/dishas/Desktop/US_aq_data/'+place+'/'+place+'_'+'PM2.5_'+str(year)+'_YTD.csv'
   df=pd.read_csv(file)
   print 'file name', file
   print 'head'
   print df.head()
   print 'info'
   print df.info()
   df.columns = ['Site', 'Parameter', 'Date','Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour','AQI','AQI_C','24H', 'Value', 'Unit', 'Duration', 'QC']
   return


df1=filename(2015)
print 'outside of function - details'
print df1.head()
quit()
\\\

> Blockquote
```

Comment: you don't return anything, also you should edit the post with proper indentation not post as an answer